# How to add a non-Amber library with bower? (for example processing js)

Tags: smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I have started a project with `amber init` and then `bower install processing --save` to get [processing.js](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js) added.
I do the initialisation with

```
firstProcessingInstance

     <return Processing.instances[0]>
```

This method is called by the instance method `initialize`and it worked a pre-Amber v0.13 version.

How do I initialize Processing.js in Amber 0.13 and 0.14?

The code of the example is [here](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber-examples/tree/gh58/processing)

### Addition after answer by Herby

In version 0.13 and 0.14 a configuration file `processing.amd.json` has to be added manually to the root directory. Files `libraryname.amd.json` in the root directory of the project are needed if the library does not have a `local.amd.json` file in the library directory.

Examples for `libraryname.amd.json` files from Amber Smalltalk and Helios are

project amber; file jquery.amd.json

```
{
"paths": {
           "jquery": ["dist/jquery", "jquery"]
         }
}
```

project amber; file es5-shim.amd.json

```
{
"paths": {
           "amber_lib/es5-shim": "."
         }
}
```

project helios; file showdown.amd.json

```
{
"paths": {
    "helios/showdown": "src/showdown"
}
}
```

project: https://github.com/hhzl/Amber-snapsvg-demo
file: snap.svg.amd.json

```
{
"paths": {
          "snap.svg" : "dist/snap.svg"
         }
}
```

### References

- [Amber may be a project and a library](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Amber-project-being-application-and-library-at-once)
- [Lego bricks illustration](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Building-blocks-of-Amber-application-%28and-library%29)

### Question

What is wrong with this `processing.amd.json` library mapping file?

```
{
"paths": {
            "processing" : "processing"
         }
}
```

**Note** After a change in `processing.amd.json` run `grunt devel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding external non-Amber library to the project involves more steps than just bower install. You must create libdir.amd.json in root of the project with mapping the library file to the symbolic name. Then, you should add the symbolic name into either deploy.js or devel.js (depending on the context in which it is used), *outside* the place intended for amber packages (that is, *not* between the two delimiter comments).

EDIT: There is nothing wrong with the cited `processing.amd.json`, it's right and correct. With this, `"processing"` module name is mapped to `.../processing/processing` (`.js` is omitted from AMD mapping by design). After all, see your `config.js` to check the mapping is correct. If you have problems loading `processing.js`, it is outside this domain (`.amd.json` and Amber's mappings).

Comment: The wiki [Amber Config](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Amber-Config) page mentions ``libdir.amd.json``. However it does not give an example.

Comment: Running ``amber config`` does not generate a ``libdir.amd.json`` file.

Comment: `amber config` (btw, it is not to be used directly, use `grunt devel` which incorporates it) is _consumer_ of .amd.json files, not its producer. You must write libdir.amd.json yourself (and of course, it cannot be generated, because _only you_ know what you want to map and how).

Comment: There are lots of examples of libdir.amd.json in Amber itself. Or in Helios.

Comment: Made the question more specific using the answer. What is wrong with ``processing.amd.json``?

Comment: And what do I need to run after changing ``processing.amd.json``?

Comment: `grunt devel` lorem ipsum

Comment: Added answer to new part of the question.