# How to load external librarie i.e. moment.js in Amber-Smalltalk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I don't get moment.js or other external libraries like tinymce working in my amber application.

These are the steps I did so far:

1. run `bower install moment --save`
2. added a moment.and.json in my applications root directory containing the correct path in bower_components:
   `{"paths": {"moment": "moment"}}`
3. added "moment" to deploy.js
4. run `grunt devel`

My first problem is that from inside the js console momentjs seems to be not loaded, even if the file shows up in network traffic.

After that how do I use moment.js from inside Amber?
How do I need to wrap it?

I read [how-to-add-a-non-amber-library-with-bower-for-example-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374889/how-to-add-a-non-amber-library-with-bower-for-example-processing-js) and all the other explanations but still have problems grabbing the exact process.

All the documentation I read was inconclusive to me. Isn't there a simple explanation on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The amd file has to look like this:

```
{
    "paths": {
       "moment": "moment"
    },
    "shim": {
       "moment": {
         "exports": "moment"
       }
    },
    "config": {
       "moment": {
         "noGlobal": false
       }
    }
}
```

As it seems it has to be required like this to work properly: `window.moment = require('moment');`

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes it works and sometimes not. I don't get why.